# What is the syntax error in this simple SQL query for creating a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, datagrip

I am trying out IntelliJ's DataGrip to do some SQL work on a MariaDB database.

Somehow i cannot execute the query that was automatically created by DataGrip itself....

Can you help me find the error in it ?

```
create table currencyIndex
(
    id int auto_increment,
    isoCode VARCHAR2(3) not null,
    isoCodeNumeric SMALLINT not null,
    currencyName VARCHAR2(100) not null,
    countryName VARCHAR2(100) not null,
    constraint currencyIndex_pk
        primary key (id)
);
```

The error is

```
[42000][1064] (conn=246) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(3) not null,
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(3) not null,
    isoCodeNumeric SMALLINT not null,
    currencyName VARCHAR2(100) ...' at line 4.
```

I tried to validate the query with an online validator and it seems fine... Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is VARCHAR2 ? Why not to use just VARCHAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB and MySQL do not have a `VARCHAR2` type (but Oracle does).  Use plain `VARCHAR` and the error should go away:

```
CREATE TABLE currencyIndex (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    isoCode VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    isoCodeNumeric SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    currencyName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    countryName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT currencyIndex_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks man... strange this validator of MySql says its fine https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: I can speculate and say maybe its creators got lazy and just have a single fixed set of allowed column types.  The only validation you need is against the actual database.  Check out the demo link I gave, it is working now.